# skip the first input of a text file in c

Tags: c

Anyone knows how to do this in C Language?

INPUT: (input.txt)

```
2 WORD WORD WORD
```

OUTPUT:

```
File contains: 2 word
Word are: WORD WORD
```

*I'am new in C Programming, and i am practicing my self.
i have a little code, but not fixing yet this problem.
here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE* f = fopen("input.txt","r");
    char c;
    int l = 1;

    if(f == NULL){
        printf("File not found!");
        return;
    }
    c = getc(f);
    while(c != EOF){
        if(c == ' '){
            l++;
        }
        c = getc(f);
    }
    fclose(f);

    printf("File contain: %d word",l);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do the input file always start with a number, followed by three space-delimited words? Then why not read it all in one go with [`fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) (which allow you to read but discard some input).

Comment: Also, with your current code you make a very common beginners mistake: You declare `c` as a `char`, but [`getc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an `int`. This will cause problems with your loop condition, because `(char) EOF != (int) EOF`

Comment: Please add more detail, what you want to skip, your sample `input.txt` etc.

Comment: I don't understand your example. Please use common placeholders (foo, bar, baz).

Comment: Sorry for misunderstand example,
INPUT:
2 WORD WORD WORD

so first, the program will read the file containing an input file, it will read first the number of word that will be count,
in this case the program read first the '2' so the program will count only the 2 words, and other follow word will not be count,
and after counting, it will display the first '2' words and other following word will not be included in displaying.

Comment: Does your input have punctuation marks? What's the expected output of `3 Hi, it's an example!`?

Comment: no, there's no punctuation mark there, the expected output is
`File contains: 2 words /* Even there is another word follow */`
`Word are: WORD WORD`

Comment: Note: Rather than `char c; ... c = getc(f); while(c != EOF){`, should use `int c`.  Otherwise one of the 256 different `char` will have the same value as `EOF` and the `while(c != EOF)` will not know if the loop is stopped due to a true EOF or that `char`.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Agree about the need for `int c`.  But `(char) EOF != (int) EOF` is confusing as when `char` is signed, which is common, `(char) EOF` does equal `(int) EOF`.  I see the failure as there are typically 256 different `unsigned char` and `EOF` returned from `getc()` and `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`,  cannot distinguish 256 + 1 different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *f = fopen("input.txt","r");
    int wc, first_time = 1;
    char word[128];

    fscanf(f, "%d", &wc);
    printf("File contain: %d word\n", wc);
    printf("Word are: ");

    fscanf(f, "%*s");//skip
    while(1==fscanf(f, "%127s", word)){
        if(first_time)
            first_time = !first_time;
        else
            printf(" ");
        printf("%s", word);
    }
    printf("\n");
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
int c, wc, first_time = 1;
char word[128];

fscanf(f, "%d", &wc);
printf("File contain: %d word\n", wc);
printf("Word are: ");

c = 0;
while(1==fscanf(f, "%127s", word) && c++ < wc){
```

Comment: i dont think so,
`INPUT: 2 WORD WORD WORD`
The output of your code is:
`File contain: 2 word`
`Word ar: WORD WORD`

yes but when i change the input to

`INPUT: 2 WORD1 WORD2 WORD3`
The output of your code is:
`File contain: 2 word`
`Word ar: WORD2 WORD3`

the "WORD1" is also skip and not displaying.. 
since that input contains '2' and 'WORD1 WORD2 WORD3'
the output for displaying the words will be 'WORD1' and 'WORD2'...

Comment: @Seynal I took it for granted that to skip the first input from the contents of the title. I'll add the number read the conditions of the loop.

Comment: @Seynal _skip the first input of a text file_ So, what would you skip?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `fgets()` to read the line and then spilt the line into words. Once its spilt it will be easy for you to do your validation.

Comment: can you give me a guide on how to do that with fgest()?

Comment: Documentation on 'fgets()' can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/). You provided it with a char[], the maximum size of your line to be read, and the file pointer you are reading from. The example in the documentation should explain it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be start by reading a line using `fgets`, strip leading (and possibly trailing) whitespace.

If the first character is a digit (use e.g `isdigit`) then use `strtol` to convert to a number, and followed by splitting the words in the read line using fgets as needed continuing in a loop until you finish the lines in the input file.